# Why does the Windows console silently strip away any non-ASCII input characters? And how do I fix/get around it?

Tags: php, windows, unicode, windows-10, windows-console

I start my PHP CLI script with a start.bat containing this:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 > NUL
php engine.php
```

The "chcp 65001" part is specifically to make it use Unicode (but it doesn't).

engine.php contains:

```
<?php

    $input = fgets(STDIN);
    var_dump($input);
```

When I run start.bat, it opens a console with engine.php running:

```
åäölöäå
string(9) "   l
"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see, it strips away every character except for the "l". This means that my scripts which rely on me pasting a text as the input break, which completely cripples my workflow. I need to be able to paste any string I have copied into my script and have it survive perfectly.

Why does this happen? What can we do to get around it?

Please don't tell me to use PowerShell. It's a bloody broken mess and also seems to behave the same even when I force it to run (I never want to deal with that again). Also, I don't have the Windows Terminal yet, so I'm stuck with classic console for at least a few more years.

Comment: This has nothing inherently to do with cmd.exe. php.exe is attached to a system console, which is hosted by an instance of conhost.exe. It happens to have inherited this console from cmd.exe, which previously executed chcp.com to change the console's input and output codepages to 65001 (UTF-8). powershell.exe is also a console application, which allocates/attaches to the exact same console as cmd.exe, chcp.com, or php.exe.

Comment: conhost.exe is broken for UTF-8 input with the bytes API functions `ReadConsoleA` and generic `ReadFile`, which encode the console input buffer using the input codepage. The implementation assumes a single-byte encoding, with one byte per character, but UTF-8 has 2-4 bytes per non-ASCII character. Thus with codepage 65001, the console is limited to 7-bit ASCII. Prior to Windows 10, it returns success with 0 bytes read, which looks like EOF. In Windows 10 it returns the buffer containing any ASCII characters, with all non-ASCII characters replaced by null characters (`"\x00"`).

Comment: The only working Unicode solution is to use the console's wide-character function, `ReadConsoleW`, to read UTF-16LE text. I don't think php.exe supports this out of the box, but there may be a way to call the Windows API directly using a foreign-function library or some kind of extension module. I don't know php, so I can't help there.

Comment: What happens when you use a different terminal emulator, e.g. [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)?

Comment: I haven't tried those third-party softwares, because I want to use real/vanilla software only.

Comment: PHP has an [FFI extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ffi.php), which you can use to call [`ReadConsoleW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole). The buffer that's read from the console will be encoded as UTF-16LE. PHP should have a facility to transcode this to UTF-8. If not, you can call WINAPI [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte). Printing UTF-8 to the console (ultimately via `WriteFile` or `WriteConsoleA`) works okay in Windows 8 and above, but not Windows 7 and below.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem in Windows 10 and PHP 7.2.

Solved it switching to `readline()` function instead of `fgets()`.

Combined with the Unicode codepage, set by `chcp 65001`, received input is now valid UTF8. No conversion needed.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php